Combine 2 numpy 1d arrays taking elements from each consecutively
I have 2 arrays
xs1 = [ x0,  x1,  x2,  x3,  x4,  x5,  x6,  x7,  x8]
xs2 = [x00, x01, x02, x03, x04, x05, x06, x07, x08]

I want to combine them taking an element from each at a time.
xs = [x0, x00, x1, x01, x2, x02, x3, x03, x4, x04, x5, x05, x6, x06, x7, x07, x8, x08]

How can i achieve this with numpy without a for loop?

we can use array indexing to fill xs
xs = np.empty(len(xs1) + len(xs2), dtype=xs1.dtype)
xs[0::2] = xs1
xs[1::2] = xs2

output
[x0, x00, x1, x01, x2, x02, x3, x03, x4, x04, x5, x05, x6, x06, x7, x07, x8, x08]


import numpy as np

aa = np.array(['x0', 'x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x5', 'x6', 'x7', 'x8'])
bb = np.array(['x00', 'x01', 'x02', 'x03', 'x04', 'x05', 'x06', 'x07', 'x08'])

combined1 = np.vstack((aa,bb)).flatten('F')
print(combined1)
'''
['x0' 'x00' 'x1' 'x01' 'x2' 'x02' 'x3' 'x03' 'x4' 'x04' 'x5' 'x05' 'x6'
 'x06' 'x7' 'x07' 'x8' 'x08']
'''
combined2 = np.stack((aa,bb),axis=0).flatten('F')
print(combined2)
'''
['x0' 'x00' 'x1' 'x01' 'x2' 'x02' 'x3' 'x03' 'x4' 'x04' 'x5' 'x05' 'x6'
 'x06' 'x7' 'x07' 'x8' 'x08']
'''
combined3 = np.column_stack((aa, bb)).ravel()
print(combined3)
'''
['x0' 'x00' 'x1' 'x01' 'x2' 'x02' 'x3' 'x03' 'x4' 'x04' 'x5' 'x05' 'x6'
 'x06' 'x7' 'x07' 'x8' 'x08']
'''

